# Can you spot the logic error in this code? Counts

Tags: c

I have a problem with a program I wrote. I can't get the word count right for the string coming in but I get the longest character count correct. I'm not sure why but here is my code. What I'm doing is passing one string to a function that capitalizes all letters in the string. that same function then determines character by character if it is in the A-Z range, if it is it adds one the the longest consecutive character A-Z count called charcount. then from there it should find if the previous character was not in the A-Z range. if not the a new word is counted. the array at the end passes the counts to the main function. ignore all the extra strings. The point here is something is off with my word count and I cannot find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char s[], int counts[]);

int main(void)
{
     int i = 0;
     int aray[2];
     char text0[] = "This is one of Several strings2use.";
     char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
     char text2[] = "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)";
     char text3[] = "Twitter loves its hashtags #twitterlove";
     char text4[] = "123 four five.";
     convert(text3,aray);
     printf("wordcount is %d and longest char is %d ", aray[0],aray[1]);




}

void convert(char s[], int counts[])
{
     int i = 0;

     while(s[i] != '\0')
     {
         if('a' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'z')
          {   s[i] = s[i] - 32; }
         i = i + 1;
     }
     int h = 0;
     int wordcount = 0;
     int maxcount = 0;
     int charcount = 0;
     while(s[h] != '\0')
     {
         if('A'<= s[h]&& s[h] <= 'Z')
         {    
             charcount = charcount + 1;
             if ('A' >= s[h-1] && s[h-1] >= 'Z'); """if previous not in range"""
             {
                 wordcount = wordcount + 1;} """problem here"""
         }
         else
             charcount = 0;
         if(charcount>maxcount)
             {
             maxcount = charcount;
             }
        h = h+1;         

     }
         counts[0] = wordcount;
         counts[1] = maxcount;


}
```

Comment: Debugging your code is the best thing you can do now.

Comment: ive been looking but i cant spot it, i think its something to do with my A-Z if statements

Comment: don't post `C` code with Python-style comments, and try to keep it in order and indented. Regarding how to spot errors, often times activating all the warning from the compiler helps spotting the error/s with almost no effort from your part.

Comment: What about that semicolon... It terminates the IF statement: `if ('A' >= s[h-1] && s[h-1] >= 'Z'); """if previous not in range"""`

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
if ('A' >= s[h-1] && s[h-1] >= 'Z');
```

... the body of the if statement is the "`;`". The block after it is just a plain block and will always execute. You need to delete the semicolon.

Comment: Nice catch! We all saw it but ignored it, I guess, except you :)

Answer (score 3):

I just compiled your code with warnings enabled (`gcc test.c -Wall`), and this is what I got:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12:11: warning: unused variable ‘text4’ [-Wunused-variable]
      char text4[] = "123 four five.";
           ^
test.c:10:11: warning: unused variable ‘text2’ [-Wunused-variable]
      char text2[] = "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)";
           ^
test.c:9:11: warning: unused variable ‘text1’ [-Wunused-variable]
      char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
           ^
test.c:8:11: warning: unused variable ‘text0’ [-Wunused-variable]
      char text0[] = "This is one of Several strings2use.";
           ^
test.c:6:10: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
      int i = 0;
          ^
test.c: In function ‘convert’:
test.c:40:51: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
              if ('A' >= s[h-1] && s[h-1] >= 'Z'); """if previous not in range"""
                                                   ^
test.c:41:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
              {
              ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:19:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

These warnings usually do make sense, and they usually have a point. So in order to fix the problems with your code, the first thing you should do now, is to fix these warnings (and errors).

Then you should learn to use debugging tools, e.g., `gdb`, to step through the execution path of the application and inspect the contents of your variables at runtime. Unless you are somewhat experienced to get along by educated guesswork, this is the essence to enable you identify the problems with your logic yourself.

It can also be helpful to start working on a function by outlining the algorithm using comments or pseudocode before writing actual code. When you have arrived at a logic that seems to make sense you can fill in the implementation as necessary. Working out a good design upfront can save you hours or days of later debugging.